# How to document the paths of my windows service in an easy to read diagram?

Tags: manual-testing, documentation, coverage

I have a windows service that issues thousands of android ADB commands to devices, I plan to go through the source for it and document all possible scenarios/paths, there are a lot of if *x* do *y* scenarios, I want a documented flow/path diagram I can provide to the QA team to aid in test case writing.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there a specific name for this type of diagram, are there online websites that can aid in the creation of said diagram?

I don't want any scenario missed here and some scenarios only occur rarely so I want to list every possible path through this windows service execution.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a specific type/name for this documentation, but you can use [draw.io](https://draw.io) to create a flow/path diagram as you mentioned. You can also explore the different types of diagrams they have and see if any of them is a good fit.